# Initialize bean value from another bean (once)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to set a value of bean from another bean once a page is displayed. The target dataTable is included because it is also used in another context.
Like I said before, there are two beans involved:

- bean1 'gets' a parameter, will load an object and display some properties.
- bean2 is the bean that is responsible for the filtering / search in the dataTable.

relevant parts:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="objectId" value="#{bean1.objectId}" />
</f:metadata>
<!-- resolving works -->
#{bean1.object.name}
```

included search:

```
<p:dataTable>...<p:inputText value="#{bean2.value}">...</p:dataTable>
```

How to assign (a substring of) bean1.object.name to the value of the input text once at page request but keep the existing value attribute of the field? I don't want to mess up the included page but would prefer to solve it "outside" in my including jsf/xhtml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using javascript. 
Define a input hidden tag to hold the value of #{bean1.object.name}. 
Now in javascript get the value of this field using document.getElementById("").value 
Take the substring and assign to input text field using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I was totally in the jsf world and forgot about simple js ;) But now I got an additional autocomplete field: I can set the string in the field but it does not convert it to a real object like it would do if I enter the content manually. Maybe this might be a new question :)